# Simple C# JSON-RPC (Client only) Using HTTPClient

Tags: c#, json-rpc

There are several examples out there including AustinHarris.JsonRPC which include fully packaged JSON-RPC servers.

Those that I can find for clients seem to just use Byte stream reading.  I'm trying to find a simple implementation using a HTTPClient as I understand it to be among the most efficient means of JSON requests available in .NET

Essentially I just need a simple outer shell to handle the model for the generic JSON-RPC structure and the sending and receiving of the data.  The data that is returned will then be extracted from the outer JSON-RPC object and converted into *strongly typed* entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this NuGet package for .NET Standard 1.1 (and higher) which provides a serializer / deserializer for JSON-RPC 2.0 messages: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.JsonRpc.